# jQuery search by class AND css value NOT equal to foo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure where to look in the jQuery documentation to find this. I have a jQuery element that I found on the DOM.

Within that, I want all elements with `class == 'bar'` and css value `'display' == 'none'`.  The first part is easy:

```
$myElement.find(".bar");
```

How can I get all elements within this list where the css value `'display' == 'none'`?

All in one line if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
$myElement.find(".bar").filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
}).Apply_your_jQuery_method_now();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
 $myElement.find(".bar").filter(":hidden"); //you have all display:none ones
```

Comment: The problem is, an element can be hidden because its parent is hidden.

Comment: @RahaelDDL Or :) `$myElement.find(".bar:hidden");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
$myElement.find(".bar:not(:visible)");
```

Comment: Why use `:not(:visible)`, when there's `:hidden`? )